# On continuous part of the L^2 spectrum

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, automorphic-forms

Suppose $G$ is a real reductive Lie group and $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $G$ (of finite co-volume). I am reading Langlands's paper " On the functional equation satisfied by the Eisenstein series". I have the following question: Does the construction of Eisenstein series discussed in this paper describe how it contributes non-trivially to the continuous part ( i.e. the compliment of the cuspidal spectrum) of $L^2(\Gamma \backslash G)$?

In one of the M$\ddot{u}$ller's paper I have seen the explicit affirmative answer to the above question in the special case of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, where he has given a non-trivial section from the continuous part.

Comment: In principle, yes. It may be hard to read, though. For cleaner statements you may check the early papers of Arthur on the trace formula.

Comment: @Corbennick: Thanks a lot. Will look at Arthur's papers